# What is the minimal Java class file that works on every JVM?

Tags: java, jvm, .class-file

I want a sort of minimal "smoke test" for a series of JVMs, ranging from JDK 1 - 8, OpenJDK, IBM JDK, and even Microsoft JDKs if possible. Is there a way to make a minimal Java class file that should be able to test this?

## Update

It should be possible to run:

java -cp ClassName

And have output that confirms that the JVM is running properly.

Also, for those who think that JVMs are always functioning should know that I use systems which have up to 20 JVMs on one machine, and some of the JVMs can be corrupted. Also note that not all JVMs can run all .class files

Comment: What do you want to test? That the JVM can boot?

Comment: @Thilo - I want to test that the JVM starts up and runs the Java class.

Comment: @Peter. It could be HelloWorld if that is 100% guaranteed to run on every JVM. If that is so then post it as the answer, together with how you made the Java class

Comment: @Zubair lets say a JVM1.1-API is the reference, Kirti's answer is right.

Comment: @Peter. If everyone agrees then I will accept this answer. And I will wait for Kirti to modify it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Krakatau has [an example aseembler file](https://github.com/Storyyeller/Krakatau/blob/master/examples/minimal.j)  for the minimal classfile.

```
.class public minimal
.super java/lang/Object
```

This will give you the simplest possible classfile that will load in the JVM. It doesn't have all the optional metadata that you'll usually get from other tools (Jasmin for instance always adds a SourceFile attribute). This isn't the shortest possible file since you can shave off a few bytes by shortening the class name, but it's basically the simplest possible class.

Note that while this class will load, it doesn't contain any code so you can't meaningfully *execute* it. If you want something you can run as the entry point, you'll need to add a main function. This can be done by adapting the [Hello World](https://github.com/Storyyeller/Krakatau/blob/master/examples/hello.j) example to remove the printing code.

```
.class public Code
.super java/lang/Object

.method public static main : ([Ljava/lang/String;)V
    .limit stack 10
    .limit locals 10

    return
.end method
```

This will give you a class that is runnable, and which immediately returns. So it's the simplest possible class with a main function.

Answer (score 5):

The [Java Compatibility Kit](http://openjdk.java.net/groups/conformance/JckAccess/) (JCK) is developed for this exact purpose. A minimal jar would not be sufficient to check for a JVM implementation's correctness  as there are many corner cases to cover and any combination of byte code instructions need to be supported.

If you simply wanted to check if a minimal program runs, compile a simple class with an empty `main` method to a Java class file format in version 1. Due to Java's backwards compatibility, this should be understandable by any JVM and the JVM should exit with status code `0`.

Comment: The requirements to access that compatibility kit are pretty tough. It doesn't look like something available to ordinary developers.

Comment: It is available including the sources. However, you are not allowed to compile or use it. This is also why the Apache Software Foundation left the Java Community Process.

Comment: I don't want to check the JVM's correctness, just to make sure it can start and run something, as I realise there are alot of class files that all JVM cannot execute the same

Comment: I'm not sure what kind of JVMs you are running, but they should be compatible. Often, implementers also provide a check sum to test the validity of an installation. Running a sample program seems like a bad way of validating a JVM's functionality.

Comment: Is there a program I can use to check a JVM if I provide the JVM path such as c:\jdk1.7?

Comment: The problem I have is that when you install a JVM it sometimes stops another JVM of the same version working, when done with the Oracle installer, so not checking compatibility, but checking whether the JVM is in working condition.

Comment: Then the hello world test is insufficient. Your installation could be broken. I would recommend checksums of the installation.

Answer (score 3):

Any class that have a main method can execute on any jvm this can be the minimal case to test, e.g.:

```
class Hello {
    public static void main (String args[])
    {
        System.out.println("hello");
    }
}
```

Comment: `javac -target 1.1 Hello.java`

Comment: It's not minimal unless you remove the System.out.println().